# Slick slider растягивается на большое разрешение

Tags: html, css, jquery, slick.js, slider-slick.js

Есть такой слайдер.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.1-11.ru/js/slick/slick/slick-theme.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.1-11.ru/js/slick/slick/slick.css"/>

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.1-11.ru/js/slick/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.slider7_container').slick({
    arrows: true,
    autoplay: true,
    autoplaySpeed: 5000,

    infinite: true,
    speed: 500,
    fade: true,
    prevArrow: '<span u="arrowleft" class="jssora01l" style="left:8px;  z-index:1;"></span>',
    nextArrow: '<span u="arrowright" class="jssora01r" style="right:8px; "></span>',

    cssEase: 'linear'

  });
});
```

```
    <div class="slider7_container" style="max-width:1440px; position: relative; top: 0px; left: 0px;">
    <div><a href="http://www.1-11.ru/oformlene-kabineta"><img style="width:100%;" alt=" " title=" " u="image" src="http://www.1-11.ru/images/banners/001_new.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div><a href="http://www.1-11.ru/oformlene-kabineta"><img style="width:100%;" alt=" " title=" " u="image" src="http://www.1-11.ru/images/banners/002_new.jpg" /></a></div>

    <div><a href="http://www.1-11.ru/oformlene-kabineta"><img style="width:100%;" alt=" " title=" " u="image" src="http://www.1-11.ru/images/banners/003_new.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div><a href="http://www.1-11.ru/oformlene-kabineta"><img  style="width:100%;" alt=" " title=" " u="image" src="http://www.1-11.ru/images/banners/004_new.jpg" /></a></div>
    <div><a href="http://www.1-11.ru/oformlene-kabineta"><img style="width:100%;" alt=" " title=" " u="image" src="http://www.1-11.ru/images/banners/005_new.jpg" /></a></div>
    </div>
```

Он находиться внутри `<td width="75%" height="100%" valign="top">`
Проблема в том, что если я убираю размер у `class="slider7_container"` Слайдер растягивается на ширину 30000px и не берет ширину родителя.

Неудачный скрипт, для изменения ширины.

```
function ScaleSlider() {
        var parentWidth = $('.slider7_container').parent().width();
        if (parentWidth) {
            //var width = document.documentElement.clientWidth;
            var width = window.screen.width;
            var width_new = width*3/4;
            //$(".slider7_container").width(parentWidth);
            $(".slider7_container").width(width_new);
        }
        else
            window.setTimeout(ScaleSlider, 100);
    }
    //Scale slider after document ready
    ScaleSlider();

    //Scale slider while window load/resize/orientationchange.
    $(window).bind("load", ScaleSlider());
    $(window).bind("resize", ScaleSlider());
    $(window).bind("orientationchange", ScaleSlider());
    //responsive code end
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `width: inherit` не пробовали, чтобы принять ширину родителя?

Comment: http://www.1-11.ru/?cat=6
Не помогло. Пробовал через скрипт не большой, но на ноутбучном разрешении, появл. горизонтальный бегунок

Comment: а добиться чего хотите?

Comment: На главной странице стоит старый слайдер. Хочу сделать подобный.

Comment: Slick Slider всегда выставляет ширину в 100% от родителя. Он не может растянуться на 30000px;. Но насколько я знаю этот слайдер, единственное, что может его так растянуть - это элементы, которые должны прокручиваться и видимо они у вас не скрыты. Проверьте класс .slick-track - он отвечает за прокрутку внутренних элементов и это именно у него видимо выставлено 30000px; А у элемента выше slick-track, вроде называется slick-clip - должно быть по идее overflow: hidden;, чтобы элементы slick-track вращались внутри slick-clip

Answer (score 0):

```
.slider7_container{
  max-width: 1500px;
}
```

Comment: постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развернутые ответы. [edit]